# I can't convert my datetime into mins, seconds and etc

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm giving `2022-03-12T22:57:20.734546Z` as the date argument. I give the datetime as input and then check using conditions and returning `foo seconds ago` or `foo mins ago` etc but I'm getting output as `20 seconds ago` and its not updating.

```js
const convertDate = (date: string) => {

    let d = moment(date).seconds();
    let min = d / 60;
    let hours = d / 3600
    let day = d / 86400
    let month = day / 30
    let year = month / 12


     if (min <= 60) {
        return `${min} min(s) ago`
    } else if (hours <= 60) {
        return `${hours} hour(s) ago`
    } else if (day <= 30) {
        return `${day} day(s) ago`
    } else if (month <= 30) {
        return `${month} month(s) ago`
    } else if (year <= 365 ) {
        return `${year} year(s) ago`
    } else {
        return `${d} second(s) ago`
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### From moment.js docs

```js
moment(date).fromNow();     // 4 years ago
moment(date).fromNow(true);     // 4 years
```

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the seconds ago by comparing to the current date as in the example below.
[Working Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-v5t8ct)
As of today, moment is no longer needed, and you can use pure javascript to convert a string to date object. Source :
[Momentjs documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/) or [check this article](https://dockyard.com/blog/2020/02/14/you-probably-don-t-need-moment-js-anymore)

> Moment was built for the previous era of the JavaScript ecosystem. The modern web looks much different these days.

```
const convertDate = (date: string) => {
  let current_date = new Date().getTime();

  let d = (current_date - new Date(date).getTime()) / 1000;

  let min = Math.round(d / 60);
  if (min <= 60) {
    return `${min} min(s) ago`;
  }

  let hours = Math.round(d / 3600);
  if (hours <= 60) {
    return `${hours} hour(s) ago`;
  }

  let day = Math.round(d / 86400);
  if (day <= 30) {
    return `${day} day(s) ago`;
  }

  let month = Math.round(day / 30);
  if (month <= 30) {
    return `${month} month(s) ago`;
  }

  let year = Math.round(month / 12);
  if (year <= 365) {
    return `${year} year(s) ago`;
  }

  return `${d} second(s) ago`;
};
```